# Color scheme for a 2D matrix where near points are colored similarly

Tags: numpy, matplotlib, matrix, colors

I have a 2D matrix of 2-tuples representing `x,y` coordinates which I plot using `plt.scatter()`, resulting in a square grid of points. I'd like to color all points in different colors in such a way so nearby points (Euclidean or Manhattan distance, doesn't really matter) are colored in similar colors, while taking advantage of a wide as possible range of colors for the whole grid (so points in general are as distinguishable as possible). How can this be achieved?

Comment: Do you have an example of the sort of display you want?

Comment: @kwinkunks Not really. The motivation is simulating a dynamical system operating on different points in phase space over time and being able to visually follow the fate of points that started out close to each other - I'm open to different ways of achieving this

Comment: Maybe start with red in one corner and vary blue along one axis, and green along the other, i.e. if `(i,j)` is the normalized grid index, `(1-i*j, i, j)` could be the RGB color of that position.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest This works nicely. Do you want to post the solution as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: I think the question is a bit broad, so I think I cannot answer it really. Feel free to narrow it down a bit and answer it yourself with some runnable code based on my comment.